# link rel - deserialization, java wrapper

Tags: java, xml, deserialization

How to deserialize this xml:

```
<player>
<name>John</name>
<link rel="self" href="/state/XYZ2" type="application/xml"/>
```

to this java wrapper:

```
public class Player implements Serializable { 

private String name;
// How to deserialize href to string ?
```

}

Comment: This XML is not well-formed. With the missing `</player>` at the end, you could use JAXB or XPath.

Comment: ok, and how to create java wrapper, for name - i have a simple String, what a structure for link?

Comment: Arthur told you. You need to use a framework like JAXB or Xpath.

Comment: I am using RestEasy framework with jaxb. But I need to create request (xml) and on the beginning I need to create java wrapper for this xml. For name tag I have a simple String, I don't have any idea what I should create for link ?